# Read multiple ports

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

I'm trying to read from a large range of UDP ports (10k) but I want to do so without creating 10k sockets and listen to them (and use `epoll`). One solution for this is to use iptables and write rules to forward packets to a single port that the server is listening on. However, I must be able to read the original destination port in the code.

Does anybody know if it's even possible to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: You can read the packets in promiscuous mode with libtins or libpcap

Comment: I'm trying to implement a HA-solution for a RTP server without using pacemaker, corosync etc. BGP handles the failover and the failover-server is already listening.

Comment: @gj13 seems like a even worse solution than creating 10k sockets and listen to them :P

Comment: @gj13 might not be as bad if I have a firewall that blocks all other incoming ports infront of the machine.. Do you have any experience of performance in promiscuous mode?

Comment: Why would you need 10k ports? One is enough.

Comment: No, it's not. You can't determine where to send the RTP when it was setup by sdp. You will see local ip addresses in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this using the network tunneling interface (tun). If you use iptables to forward to your tun device, then your program could read packets from there. (You'd need to interpret the IP headers yourself, though, perhaps using a library like libtins.)

There's a decent tutorial here: http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/

Comment: I'll think i will use a user space udp stack to solve this (using netmap or somethng similar) but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

'recvfrom' can get the remote sockaddr and then using inet_ntop and ntohs to get ip and port.

Comment: Would work if it's a generic server but i'm trying to implement this for a RTP-server and NAT kills this solution.